# Editing - ordered list with letters.

Tags: support, feature-request, mathjax, editing, markdown

I just edited: [Let $f$ be a non-constant entire function such that $\left \lvert f(z) \right\lvert=1$ for every $z$ with $\left \lvert z \right\lvert=1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253138/f-be-a-non-constant-entire-function-such-that-left-fz-right-1-for-every)

In the question there is a list of options numbered with (a) and (b) and so on. I wanted to put it in a nicer list, but how do you make an ordered list with letters instead of numbers?

If this is not possible, I would suggest that this be made possible.

Edit: I might not have been clear enough: When I edit I want to stay near to the original formatting and wording and change only what I think is needed. I have seen some questions lately where one has to choose between some options (a), (b), (c), and (d), and I just wanted to put that in a list like

1. Option
2. Option
3. Option
4. Option

with (a), (b), (c), (d) instead of 1,2,3,4. But the only way I can figure out how to do it is by making a bullet point list:

- (a) Option
- (b) Option
- (c) Option
- (d) Option

But I don't like the bullets. The question is whether there is a "pre-formatted" way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand. What happens if you just use 1, 2, 3, 4 where the problem has a, b, c, d?

Comment: @Gerry: You have to show there is an order isomorphism between then list, and that's a whole other question...

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Well, obviously the universe would implode.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether there is a pre-formatted way, but does

$\quad$(a) Option
$\quad$(b) Option
$\quad$(c) Option
$\quad$(d) Option

look like what you want?

Comment: Yeah, that pretty much is it. I might add a future suggestion tag as well to see if it could be implemented a a nice way. Thanks though for experimenting.